# Tabbarview + class model: Arrays are working weird

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a tabbar view controller in which I define arrays :

```
var customerData: [[customerInformation]] = []
var itemsData: [[Item]] = []
var totalData: [TotalInformation] = []
```

And I append elements to these arrays in my subview controller (I mean a subview to the view connected to the tabbar controller) :

```
    let tabBar = tabBarController as! baseTabBarController
    tabBar.customerData.append(customerData)
    tabBar.itemsData.append(itemsData)
    tabBar.totalData.append(totalData)
```

The problem is that when appending the existing element is too modified. Thanks.

P.S.: I have defined an another String array and the appending works fine.

Comment: what do you mean by when appending the existing element is too modified? what is the exact issue here? Why are you using two dimensional array?

Comment: I use two dimensional array because I have many customers with many information for every customer. The existing element becomes a copy of the appended element.